# Adding Loading States to flatMapLatest in Android with Firebase and Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on an Android project that utilizes Firebase for authentication and data storage. The project follows the MakeItSoApp model from the Firebase documentation and handles errors with Crashlytics through a global class that captures them. For this reason, I don't worry much about try-catch blocks for API calls within the app, as they will be handled later.

That being said, my code has been working well. It has a user, and all items I need to read have a 'userId' field that corresponds to the user who saved it in the database.

Here is an example of the user structure:

```kotlin
class AccountServiceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth

) : AccountService {
    override val currentUser: Flow<User>
        get() = callbackFlow {
            val listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
                this.trySend(auth.currentUser?.let { User(it.uid) } ?: User())
            }
            auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
            awaitClose { auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener) }
        }
}
```

Reading the data continues to work in this way.

In the service class...

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class ProductStorageServiceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore,
    private val accountService: AccountService
) : ProductStorageService {
    override val products: Flow<List<Product>>
        get() = accountService.currentUser.flatMapLatest { user ->
            firestore.collection(PRODUCTS_COLLECTION).whereEqualTo(USER_ID_FIELD, user.id)
                .dataObjects()
        }

    override suspend fun add(product: Product) {
        val productWithUserId = product.copy(userId = accountService.currentUserId)
        firestore.collection(PRODUCTS_COLLECTION).add(productWithUserId).await()
    }
}
```

Followed by the ViewModel class...

```
    var products: Flow<List<Product>> = productStorageService.products
```

And finally, the UI collects the items...

```kotlin
    val products by viewModel.products.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(emptyList())
```

After this setup, I encountered the following problem. First, I didn't quite understand why, when I add a product, my reading screen updates, as I only collect it in the Screen, and flatMapLatest is listening to the user. This confuses me, but it simply works. Now, I would like to add a loading state to my flow, something like the famous Resources class:

```kotlin
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null,
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
}
```

However, I don't have a Flow; I have a flatMapLatest...

```kotlin
accountService.currentUser.flatMapLatest
```

... the only place I have a flow to do this would be in the user, but I don't think it's correct, and not possible actually, considering that the data comes from the other class.
Thank you in advance for any guidance or suggestions!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I hope you can use the 'resource' class as the loading state for my app in database calls. @AlexMamo

Comment: The `Resource` class looks good to me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I just want to emit Resource from my flatMapLatest

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I just cant EMIT anithing on my flatMapLatest man, look, now I can do something like this on EVERY viewmodel doing a collect 
```kotlin
 init {
        launchCatching {
            productStorageService.products.collect {
                loading.value = true
                products.value = it
                loading.value = false
            }
        }
    }

```

So setting loading, and disabling it.
this work but I need to copy and paste on every viewmodel